# How should I understand "a hundred years on" in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I learned the following sentence from [*The Economist*](http://www.economist.com/node/21540385).

> **A hundred years on**, superconductors have found widespread use in just one technology, magnetic resonace imaging, which lets doctors peer inside patients' bodies.

How should I understand the phrase "a hundred years on"? There are so many meanings of the preposition "on" in the dictionary. What kind of dictionary should I refer to when I have similar problems?

Comment: Looking at [a century on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20forebears%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#pq=%22a+century+on%22&hl=en&ds=bo&cp=3&gs_id=26&xhr=t&q=%22a+century+on%22&tok=vypX051455YwymF41PcRPw&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1992%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%22a+century+on%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a36ebc11978f2e5b&biw=1238&bih=857) in NGrams, I'm surprised to see how rare it is - even **half a century on** seems to be more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A hundred years on* means *a hundred years later*; i.e. a hundred years after superconductivity was first observed.

I looked in the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*, the *Oxford English Dictionary* that's built into my Kindle and en.wiktionary.org, and the best I could find was:

> further forward; in an advanced state: *I'll see you later on; time's getting on*
>
> -- *Oxford English Dictionary*

I agree that's not very helpful when you're trying to make sense of the phrase *a hundred years on* when there are so many other possible meanings.  You have to rely on context.  Look at the headline of the article you were reading:

> Superconductors: A **century after** their discovery, superconductors are finally moving beyond scientific and medical uses and into power grids

or the preceding paragraph:

> **exactly a century ago**, he ... discovered superconductivity.

I should also mention that the *The Economist* is notable for it's sophisticated-yet-playful use of English (plus the occasional foreign word, just to make things interesting).  I consider *The Economist* the ultimate challenge for learners of English.  I'm sure there are *lots* of words and usages in *The Economist* you won't find in most dictionaries.

Comment: I like your comment about *The Economist*. `:-)` That helps a lot.

Comment: However, 'A hundred years on, superconductors ...' does not seem to necessarily imply 'a hundred years after *superconductivity was first observed*.' It does not explicitly say after what (or counting from when).

Comment: @Kris: It does imply "a hundred years after what I mentioned just now", so you have to either read the article or make a reasoned guess (bearing in mind that superconductors were discovered 100 years ago).

Answer (score 2):

*[On](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on)* functions as an adverb rather than a preposition in the sentence since it is NOT followed by a direct object.

Here is the 35th meaning of *on* from dictionary.com.

> forward, onward,  or along, as in any course or process: further on.

Answer (score 1):

Read it as: A hundred years **later**.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the sentence is as follows:

> Superconductors would have become Popular after a period of hundred years they have invented.

Comment: Please see my comment on Pitarou's answer.